# How to share the same buffer between multiple vim instances

Tags: buffers, sessions

I work with two displays.

I usually open one instance of Vim in display #1 (let's call it Vim #1), which over time ends up having an open buffer for nearly every file in a project.

Now I want to open one of the files in display #2, with a separate instance of Vim (#2). I ideally want to see the file in the same state I've got it somewhere inside Vim #1: with the same unsaved changes.

I ultimately want to have two separate Vim instances simultaneously editing one buffer (possibly sharing the same `.swp`?).

Is there a way to do that in Vim?

Comment: Perhaps the [CoVim plugin](https://github.com/FredKSchott/CoVim) works for you.

Comment: If you open a vertical split window with ctrl-w + v you'll have 2 instances. It doesnt allow for you to split over 2 physical screens if thats what you wanted, unless you make it really big so it flows over the two displays haha

Comment: never actially tried that, but wouldn't http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/remote.html solve your problem?

Comment: possible cross-site duplicate question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15444823/4748017

Comment: @HerbWolfe That question is about sharing registers. This one is actually about buffers.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt CoVim is fancy, and could be a decent fallback solution for this case, if there isn't a way to natively share a buffer across instances.

Comment: @PierrePrinetti did you read the accepted answer, though? You can't share session info between vim instances, which is what you are trying to do, by opening a buffer in multiple instances of vim.

Comment: This isn't a direct solution, but I would use tmux for this. You can connect to the same tmux instance from multiple places and they can all interact in real time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for an answer and willing to try neovim, the [neovim-remote](https://github.com/mhinz/neovim-remote) does what you need.
From the readme:

> **Open files always in the same nvim process no matter which terminal you're in.**
>
> If you just run `nvr -s`, a new nvim process will start and set its address to `/tmp/nvimsocket` automatically.
>   Now, no matter in which terminal you are, `nvr file` will always work on that nvim process.

Comment: This is not really for opening the same file in two (Neo)Vim's, but instead to open a file in an existing instance of NeoVim. For example, if you use `nvr` as your `$EDITOR`, then when you `git commit`, instead of opening a new NeoVim to type the commit message, it will ask the already running NeoVim (which might be in a GUI window) to open that file to edit it. Once you save&close the file there, `nvr` will say it's done, so `git commit` will continue. That's something original Vim has supported as `--remote` but NeoVim didn't have it natively...

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for a solution to this problem for quite a while now and just found out (pretty much by accident) that there is a GUI wrapper for Neovim, which has support for independent windows for the same instance!

https://github.com/yatli/fvim

You can detach a window into an external OS window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd>.

Unfortunately I have discovered that it doesn't really play well with some plugins, so I don't use it at the moment. It might be worth keeping an eye on the following list to see if any of the other GUI wrappers implement a similar feature: https://github.com/topics/neovim-guis

---

*Edit:* I have just found some more approaches towards a solution to the same problem:

- https://github.com/codeape2/vim-multiple-monitors
- https://github.com/glacambre/nwin